# Radix-8 butterfly with Winograd and Cooley-Tukey algorithm

Tags: fft, dft, algorithms

I saw the Winograd radix-8 kernel algorithm below, shown in the image. Comparing to the mathematical formula of Cooley-Tukey, there is a multiplication by $\cos$ and $\sin(\pi/8)$, which can't be easily realized by the combinations of $1$ and $\sqrt{1/2}$, which are the components used in Winograd.

As we can't realize something out of nothing, what is the mathematical trick to prove the Winograd and Cooley-Tukey are equivalent? Are there any such proof online I can read?

- **Winograd algorithm:**

  [image]
- **Cooley-Tukey algorithm:**

  [image]

Comment: i think there is a typo at the bottom left (regardiing $q(8)$) of the Winograd slide.

Comment: Yes, it should be a subtract instead of equal.

Comment: just to say that the 8=point Winograd algorithm listed above works while several others found in papers and on the web possibly have typos. or i understood/coded them wrongly

Answer (score 1):

The derivation of Winograd is non-trivial. It is based on Winograd cyclic convolution.  It is a decomposition of the FFT into a series of three matrix multiplies.  The first and last have all elements from the set {0, +/-1,+/-i, +/-i+/-1} (which are implemented as additions only), and the center matrix is a diagonal matrix of real weights.  The Winograd algorithm results in a reduced number of multiplies at the expense of a complicated ordering sequence and a larger number of addition/subtraction operations.  For an unrolled hardware implementation, the reduction of the number of multiplies can yield a considerable area savings.  For implementation in a processor that includes a multiply-accumulate, the complicated ordering generally outweighs any computational savings.

There are two references I can point you at:
Smith and Smith, Handbook of Real-Time Fast Fourier Transforms has algorithm steps to compute the Winograd FFT for various sizes up to I think 16 point, but is sparse on the derivation of the algorithm.
Blahut,"Fast Algorithms for Digital Signal Processing" has far more detail (not an easy read) on the derivation of the algorithm and has in the appendices the sets of matrices for several Winograd FFTs from 2 point to 16 point.  There are some errors in the sequence of operations that follow the matrices in that appendix.  Blahut may be hard to find, it is long out of print.